# How to copy sheets to another *specific* workbook using vba?

Tags: excel, imacros, vba

So I know the answer to the question How to copy sheets to another  workbook using vba? And here is the code I used:

```
    wb.Worksheets(1).Copy Before:=activeWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

So from this workbook called "wb", I copy the worksheet within "wb" to a new workbook called"activeWB". The before function place this sheet in front of "Sheet1".

However, I want to place the sheet from "Wb" to "Sheet1", not before or after it. I tried many many methods, but couldn't get this to work. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
wb.WorkSheets(1).UsedRange.Copy activeWB.WorkSheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

Comment: that copies only cell contents, no formatting, no named ranges, no column width, etc.

Comment: So substitute `usedrange` with `range("A1:Z10")` or whatever the used range is. Or find last row and last column first then plug those in. OP didn't really show much effort so I am not going to expend much on my end.

Comment: The point is that copying a range is different to copying a sheet.

Comment: Technically sure. Materialistically, there's a difference?

Comment: Yes. Formatting like column width, range names, formulas referencing sheets in the original workbook, none of these survive a range copy but will survive a sheet copy.

Comment: @findwindow ha! this works! i imagine i can further replace usedrange with the lastcolumn and lastrow type of things. This is definitely really helpful! though i lost my formatting, it's much better than dealing with deleting a sheet or add a new line to select to my current sheet for my own preference in this case. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @teylyn    you are totally right it. but i guess for my own purpose this solution works well enough.

Answer (score 2):

Don't overthink this. Copy the sheet. Delete the existing Sheet1. Rename the copied sheet to Sheet1

```
wb.Worksheets(1).Copy Before:=activeWB.Worksheets(1)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
activeWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
activeWB.Worksheets(1).Name = "Sheet1"
```

Comment: this is definitely a good alternative! for this project i have, i don't require much as of formatting. but for other projects, this method is definitely the go to solution! Thank you @teylyn!

Comment: i wish i could give 2 upvotes. both are really good solutions to solve my problem.